# Identify records where a given sequence of events happens within x days

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large data.table, similar in structure to `df`:

```
library("data.table")
df <- data.frame(part = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D", "B", "D", "E"), 
                 day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 15), 
                 code = c("S", "S", "P", "X", "P", "S", "P", "P", "P"))
setDT(df)
df
   part day code
1:    A   1    S
2:    B   2    S
3:    A   3    P
4:    C   4    X
5:    A   5    P
6:    D   6    S
7:    B   6    P
8:    D   7    P
9:    E  15    P
```

How can I add a column that flags records where `code` = `S` and the same `part` has `code` = `P` within 3 subsequent days? Expected result:

```
   part day code  flag
1:    A   1    S  TRUE
2:    B   2    S FALSE
3:    A   3    P FALSE
4:    C   4    X FALSE
5:    A   5    P FALSE
6:    D   6    S  TRUE
7:    B   6    P FALSE
8:    D   7    P FALSE
9:    E  15    P FALSE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this does it

```
df[, v := FALSE ]
df[code == "S", v := !is.na(
  df[code == "P"][df[code == "S"], on=c("part", "day"), roll=-3, which=TRUE]
)]

   part day code     v
1:    A   1    S  TRUE
2:    B   2    S FALSE
3:    A   3    P FALSE
4:    C   4    X FALSE
5:    A   5    P FALSE
6:    D   6    S  TRUE
7:    B   6    P FALSE
8:    D   7    P FALSE
9:    E  15    P FALSE
```

*How it works* `!is.na(x[i, which=TRUE])` tells us whether each row of `i` found a match in `x`. (This might break down if `i` finds multiple matches.) The `roll` part expands the scope of matches to cover rows that are nearby in terms of the last column being joined `on`.

I'm not sure that the `roll` value there is correct since I have never used it this way.

Comment: I think the `df[code == "S"]` part should be `.SD`, but that gave an error. I'll file a ticket.

Comment: Very clever. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can work too-

```
df$v <- as.logical((df$code== "S") *
        c(sapply(seq(1:(nrow(df)-2)), function(x)
           {
            max(df[(x:x+2),"code"] == "P")
           }),
          df[nrow(df)-1,"code"]=="P",
          df[nrow(df),"code"]=="P"))
```

Comment: This is a good alternative outside of data.table. I will file this away for later. Thank you.